# Count number of similar objects in two lists in same column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column which is a list of subject id's found in each month.

**Sample Data**

```
df <- tibble(month = month.abb[1:3], 
             id_list = list(seq(1,5,1), seq(2,9,1), seq(3,7,1)))

A tibble: 3 x 2
  month id_list  
  <chr> <list>   
1 Jan   <dbl [5]>
2 Feb   <dbl [8]>
3 Mar   <dbl [5]>
```

For each month, I would like to create a variable which denotes how many objects in each row's list are the same as the previous row's list.

It should look like this:

```
A tibble: 3 x 2
  month id_list   same
  <chr> <list>    <int>
1 Jan   <dbl [5]>  NA
2 Feb   <dbl [8]>   4
3 Mar   <dbl [5]>   5
```

I have tried

```
df %>%
  mutate(same = sum(unlist(id_list) %in% unlist(lag(id_list, 1))))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  month id_list    same
  <chr> <list>    <int>
1 Jan   <dbl [5]>    18
2 Feb   <dbl [8]>    18
3 Mar   <dbl [5]>    18
```

and

```
df %>%
  mutate(same = sum(id_list %in% lag(id_list, 1)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  month id_list    same
  <chr> <list>    <int>
1 Jan   <dbl [5]>     2
2 Feb   <dbl [8]>     2
3 Mar   <dbl [5]>     2
```

but the lists are either being combined for the whole column or are only being evaluated as the list itself, and not the objects.

What would be the best way to achieve the desired result? A solution in dpylr would be preferred but I'll be happy with any proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

Get the `lag` of the `list` column, then use `map2` to compare the corresponding `list` elements, and return with the `length` of `intersect`ing elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(same = map2_dbl(id_list, lag(id_list), 
             ~  na_if(length(intersect(.x, .y)), 0)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  month id_list    same
#  <chr> <list>    <dbl>
#1 Jan   <dbl [5]>    NA
#2 Feb   <dbl [8]>     4
#3 Mar   <dbl [5]>     5
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[, same := c(NA, lengths(Map(intersect, first(id_list, -1), id_list[-1])))]
```

gives

```
> df
   month         id_list same
1:   Jan       1,2,3,4,5   NA
2:   Feb 2,3,4,5,6,7,...    4
3:   Mar       3,4,5,6,7    5
```